# Is there a way to read variable in one route and pass that value in another route?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn node js. I want to create a variable which I want to read in a route and somehow pass it to another route. I have created a global variable and trying the same. But it gives me the value undefined. Please help.

```
const http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
const port = 5000;

function requestHandler(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    console.log("URL: ", req.url);
    
    var url = req.url;
    var n;
    if(url ==='/'){
        res.write('<h1 style="margin-top: 10vh; margin-left: 10vw;">This is the main page where you need to enter the input for n<h1>');
        readline.question('Please enter the value of n, so that I can tell you first n prime numbers: ', maxCount => {
            console.log("The value of maxCount is: ", maxCount);
            n = maxCount;
        });
        res.end(); //end the response
    }else if(url ==='/result'){
        res.write('<h1>contact us page<h1>');
        console.log("The value of n here is: ", n);
        res.end();
    }else{
        res.write('<h1>You are trying to go to a page which does not exist <h1>');
        res.end();
    }
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Server is up and running on port: ", port);
})
```

Comment: I think you should not try to re-write what people has made it nicely. I would suggest you use express - web framework for Nodejs (https://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `requestHandler` function is run on every request and every time it is run, you re-define your `n`-variable. So, cross-requests, there is no notion of the `n` variable.

Moving your `n`-variable outside of the `requestHandler` function will accomplish what you are trying to do.

Aside from that, I would strongly advise you to:

- not to use `stdin` when creating a web server.
- use another mechanism to store variables cross-request. [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) might be a good start.